# Html show image based on hashed url

Tags: html, instagram

Simply I want to show this image `url` which that's on `instagram`:

```
<img src="https://scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/269430179_619307746060977_8863061929784384401_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=ZuthlbGc4tYAX9H5CH4&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9NSiEkpQ91iKHZ9L7udb9lJ3pNtC0CR0pBAqpwhkPTHg&oe=61CD0C19&_nc_sid=a9513d" alt="">
```

when I try to show this image with the browser I don't have any problem and I can, but when I try to use `HTML` with `IMG` tag it can't appear, all of `instagram` images has `hash` or based on `hash` and we can't remove them,

How can I resolve this problem?

**updated:**

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Maybe Instagram whitelisted image call origins.

Comment: @tagi so how can I resolve this issue, it should be have a solution

Comment: @Tagi is correct, you can use server-side proxying as described in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Tagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012469/tagi) commented, Instagram is checking the HTTP `Referer` request header and blocks requests from third-party domains. This can be bypassed with server-side proxying.  For example, Nginx can be configured to proxy the images with:

```
server_name example.com;

location ~ ^/instagram-image(.*) {
  proxy_pass https://scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com$1$query_string;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;  # allows fetch() to succeed
  expires 1y;
}
```

Then, any requests to your "example.com" Nginx server would use the URI and query string to  load the image from Instagram's domain:

```
https://example.com/instagram-image/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/269430179_619307746060977_8863061929784384401_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=ZuthlbGc4tYAX9H5CH4&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9NSiEkpQ91iKHZ9L7udb9lJ3pNtC0CR0pBAqpwhkPTHg&oe=61CD0C19&_nc_sid=a9513d
  ⮑ << opens >> https://scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/269430179_619307746060977_8863061929784384401_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=ZuthlbGc4tYAX9H5CH4&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9NSiEkpQ91iKHZ9L7udb9lJ3pNtC0CR0pBAqpwhkPTHg&oe=61CD0C19&_nc_sid=a9513d
```

An `<img src="https://example.com/...">` tag will still fail, but you can use a fetch request to dynamically show the image using `fetch()`:

```js
showImage(
  document.querySelector('img'),
  'https://example.com/instagram-image/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/269430179_619307746060977_8863061929784384401_n.jpg??_nc_ht=scontent-amt2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=ZuthlbGc4tYAX9H5CH4&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT9NSiEkpQ91iKHZ9L7udb9lJ3pNtC0CR0pBAqpwhkPTHg&oe=61CD0C19&_nc_sid=a9513d'
)

async function showImage(img, url) {
  const buffer = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer()
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer]))
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, could you please help me how can i implement that on `apache` ? i don't use`nginx` now